# Change SIFR font color after page load

Tags: sifr, dynamic

Simple questions.

Can you change the color of sIFR after the flash has been applied?

I have a bit of a Google, but can't seem to find anything. Only people not being able to set the color initially.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about sIFR, but on a side note, I'd heavily recommend CSS 3 embedded fonts over the aesthetically displeasing sIFR, which is inaccessible, slow and can't be copied along with selected text.

Answer (score 0):

As Delan mentioned, I would suggest not using sIFR anymore. With the browsers currently in use, you have pretty decent CSS support. Convert your TTF to EOT for older versions of Internet Explorer, using this tool for example: http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi

Then use this CSS. In this case my font is called Techno:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Techno;
    src: url("/Techno.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: Techno;
    src: url("/Techno.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
```

This covers recent Safari (3.1+ afaik), Firefox (3.5+) and Opera versions. Mobile Safari doesn't do this, but wait, it doesn't do Flash either :)

Comment: Unfortunately, using CSS3 to for font embedding isn't possible with the fonts needed. Since you are essentially allowing the font to be downloaded. sIFR is usually supported by font makers, through an extra license, because the font is embedded in the flash files itself

Answer (score 0):

Well, after contacting the font companies, it seems I can use cufon (with the purchase if another license, which is the same as sIFR anway). S0. I have decided to go with cufon...